# Swift Actors and old dependencies

Tags: swift, concurrency, dependencies, actor, sendable

I am learning swift and trying to use the new concurrency features introduced by Swift 5.5, and to make my code conform to the new requirements that will eventually be introduced by Swift 6.

My project uses SwiftUI & MVVM as well as some dependencies (GRDB and Supabase) to sync data between a local and a remote database. I read a lot on actors and as both of those dependencies are acting as "data managers" and accessed thorough my app I feel they need to be implemented using an actor. That might be my first mistake?

Both dependencies above make heavy use of classes that inherit one another and that do not conform to the sendable protocol which creates obvious issues when trying to turn my current implementation into actors.

As an example, my initial Supabase implementation was as follow:

```
actor SupabaseManager {
    private let supabaseKey: String = "A Key"
    private let supabaseURL: String = "A URL"

    internal let db: SupabaseClient

    init(supabaseKey: String?, supabaseURL: String?) {
        db = SupabaseClient(supabaseUrl: supabaseURL ?? self.supabaseURL, supabaseKey: supabaseKey ?? self.supabaseKey) //Cannot access property 'db' here in non-isolated initializer; this is an error in Swift 6
    }
}
```

After trying a couple of things (such as making my init async, which brought other obvious issues), I was able to successfully implement Supabase by making the `db` a Singleton and getting rid of the init all together, which I don't really like as I have been using dependency injection as much as possible but can live with.

```
actor SupabaseManager {
    private static let supabaseKey: String = "A Key"
    private static let supabaseURL: String = "A URL"

    internal static let db: SupabaseClient = .init(supabaseUrl: supabaseURL, supabaseKey: supabaseKey)
}
```

Even with a successful `db` variable implementation, I still run into other issues such as the below.

```
    func fetchSync<Data_Type>(lastUpdate: Update) async throws -> [Data_Type]
        where Data_Type: SyncRecord_Protocol
    {
        let query = db.database.from(Data_Type.databaseTableName)
            .select()
            .gt(column: Data_Type.lastUpdateColumnName, value: lastUpdate.timeStamp.formatted(.iso8601))
        do {
            let response = try await query.execute() //  Non-sendable type 'CountOption?' exiting actor-isolated context in call to non-isolated instance method 'execute(head:count:)' cannot cross actor boundary
                                                     //  Non-sendable type 'PostgrestResponse' returned by call from actor-isolated context to non-isolated instance method 'execute(head:count:)' cannot cross actor boundary
            let data = try response.decoded(to: [Data_Type].self, using: supabaseDecoder())
            return data
        }
        catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
```

One way I found to make it work is to make the database function `nonisolated` and to only make it accessible through some sort of wrapping function such as what is shown below. This does not throw any error, but I am not sure if I am once again defeating the purpose of the actor

```
    func fetchSyncWrapper<DataType>(lastUpdate: Update) async throws -> [DataType]
        where DataType: SyncRecord_Protocol
    {
        return try await fetchSync(lastUpdate: lastUpdate)
    }

    nonisolated func fetchSync<Data_Type>(lastUpdate: Update) async throws -> [Data_Type]
        where Data_Type: SyncRecord_Protocol
    { ... }
```

Questions I now have are:

1. Is it even possible to adapt an older class type dependency to work with an actor, or if I have to wait for an update of the package I am using?
2. I though of making an extension to the Supabase client class to make it `@unchecked Sendable`, but I feel it defeats the purpose of the whole actor thing?

Comment: Don't those dependencies handle concurrent access to shared data already?

Comment: Good point, they do...

However, as they are not conform to the ```Sendable``` protocol, I cannot use them with ```Task{ ... }``` or some of the other concurrency features without getting warnings.

Comment: I guess we now know the downsides of using a dependency. You are dependent on the author to keep up.

Comment: I knew this was going to be one of the answers :)

Anybody has had to deal with this before? I guess that I now realize that the dependencies have mechanisms in place to deal with concurrent access, it would be fair game to use the ```@unchecked Sendable```conformance?

Comment: If it’s already thread-safe, you can just add the `@unchecked Sendable` conformance empty extension. If not, you will want to write a wrapper that is thread-safe. The `@unchecked Sendable` doesn’t “defeat the purpose”, but rather says that you’ve reviewed it and while the compiler can’t confirm it’s thread-safe, you have (assuming, of course, that it _is_ thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I ended up doing the following:

1. I found out GRDB had already updated their package and created a `GRDBSendable` type. As the types introduced by GRDB are conform to  `Sendable`, I didn't have any issue.
2. Supabase is behind on their implementation of `Sendable`, and they use a lot of subclasses related to postgREST. I made the `SupabaseClient`class `@unchecked Sendable` to facilitate the init of my wrapper. I then made an `isolated` function that wraps a `nonisolated` one to wrap everything in an actor and to make it a `Sendable` that can be used in `.task` and along with other concurrency features.